# Collections page is not showing in shopify

Tags: collections, shopify, shopify-template

Our website was working properly for a year or more and everything was fine.

One of our customer told that when they click the menu and try to open subpages which are our collections a blank page start coming . you may find the picture what is look like :  https://prnt.sc/p2_IANIp2lvm

at home page the collections works fine but not when call them like

https://kampguru.com/collections/test-collection

is there any possible answer to save our day ?

Comment: Do you use an app for filters and search? It could be an issue on their side. Also check the template that is used ander the collection settings (on the right).

Comment: I think you should disable the searchanise widget first to see if that resolves things. Unfortunately, it's not really possible to troubleshoot this without seeing the code of your collection template or main-collection section.

Comment: @pete I disable searchanise widget but this time page come total blank but at least we know the problem is at this widget , I will check it out more detailed. thanks so far.

Comment: @Pete I found that the searchanise is the exact problem thanks for your kind assist.

Comment: @FabioFilippi thanks to you too for your assist , best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@pete has solved the issue with his suggestion. The problem was the widget we have used to filter collections.
We converted collections.liquid page as it should be by commenting the widget and problem solved.